# is css syntax incompatible in .js

Tags: javascript, css

why can't a css file be included in a .js?

in other words, why can't `<style></style>` syntax be included in a .js file? the js script and css works on my page when where are in the header but when I call them externally, the css fails?

Comment: You should ask a question like "why does this CSS not work" and post the actual CSS involve, with a description of exactly what happens, what errors are reported in the browser console, etc etc. It *seems* like you've made an assumption about how things work, and it's probably incorrect.

Comment: You could import a CSS file with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot style javascript, styles apply for html tags. If you include a style tag in a javascript file, what would the styles apply for?

Comment: to answer your question, I want the content made available through the js files displayed differently than the rest of the content...for mouseover purposes

Comment: Thats what css classes are for. You could give them a class name to make them different from the rest.

Answer (score 3):

People who implemented `<script>` and `<style>` 15 or 20 years ago decided not to do that.

Things moved very, very fast in the 90s, in some ways at least.

Note that JavaScript pre-dated CSS by a couple of years. They were developed and driven by different companies. By the time CSS was invented, modifying browser JavaScript parsers to understand CSS blocks was a very unlikely thing to happen (and, in fact, it didn't).

Here's a guess: you moved one or more `<script>...</script>` blocks along with one or more `<style> ... <style>` blocks into a single file, and then tried to import it with a `<script src="something"></script>` tag.  That won't work. Your external JavaScript and CSS files need to be *pure* JavaScript and *pure* CSS.

Comment: so would this suffice:  <script type=text/javascript src=path/.js></script> <style><!-- //--></style>

Comment: @chignon I don't know what that means. Did you move your entire `<script>...</script>` and `<style>...</style>` blocks - including the HTML tags - to a separate file? If so, that doesn't work - when you use `<script>` and `<link>` tags to import JavaScript or CSS, the files must not have the HTML tags in them.

Comment: <style>...</style> yes I moved them.  so I guess move them back.  sorry I'm still learning.  So I should leave the <style> block on the main page then?

Comment: @chignon you can move the CSS stuff to a plain CSS file and then import it with a `<link>` tag - [see this summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).  You'll have *two* files: one JavaScript file (imported with a `<script>` tag) and one CSS file (via `<link>`).  You can of course have more than one of each kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way of including pure css in to a .js file, But there's an alternative.

You could use #getElementById().style.

Its not really practical but it's the only way that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons:

1. Cascading StyleSheets are describing how things look on your web page whereas JavaScript describes how things behave – they are used for completely different things.
2. Websites should work without having JavaScript enabled. At least that's what I learned in the early days. If you included straight CSS in your JavaScript and the browser had JavaScript disabled then you wouldn't see those styles applied.

Answer (score 0):

A `.js` file **only** contains Javascript. It's not an HTML file, so it isn't parsed for any kinds of `<tagname>` codes. You can't put `<style>` in it for the same reason that you don't surround the code with `<script>...</script>` inside the file (if you do this you'll get an error, because it's not Javascript). The contents of the file are treated like the contents inside a `<script>...</script>` block, and you're not allowed to put `<style>` in there, either -- it's **only** script code.